# Regular Expression, negative look behind javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

My problem seems trivial, yet I can't quite seem to grasp what I am doing wrong. I am trying to detect the end of sentences by using a regular expression to find periods. The thing is, I only want say, periods that come after a word with more than 2 letters in it, that way I can avoid a false positive of "St. Nicholas."

My current expression is:

```
/\w{3,}\./g
```

However, this seems to select the whole word, rather than just the period. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
I am expecting

```
"St. Kitts is really cool. Like seriously, sweet."
```

To return the period after both "cool" and "sweet", but not after "St."

EDIT 2:
This is in Javascript, so a normal lookbehind of (?<=text) will not work

Comment: Yes because it will match word with length `3` or **more**. You need to revise your matching condition.

Comment: `(?<=\w{3})\.` This will match if period have 3 letters before it.

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing this in Javascript and cannot do a normal lookbehind.

Comment: `\w{3}(?=\.)` can be used to match 3 letters followed by a period. Is this condition useful for your purpose ? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM5sW1/2)

Comment: I really just want to select the period if it is possible. I am using this to take a  string, and display only the first n sentences. I do this by splitting the string at each of the sentence ends, then joining the first n items in the list together by replacing the period lost in the split.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups:

```
var myRegexp = \w{3,}(\.);
var match = myRegexp.exec(your string);
alert(match[1]);  // Here you should have captured the period
```

And if there is more than one period:

```
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
    // matched period: match[1]        
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```